# How do I setup 410 response headers on all subfolders except root?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have two domains pointing to the same Wordpress root on my website. Lets call them ab.com and cd.com.

Right now all URLs from cd.com 301-redirects to ab.com.

This is what I need:
- "cd.com" should 301-redirect to ab.com
- "cd.com/*" (everything) should return a 410

Hope you can help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ - [R=410,L]
```

This will return a 410 `Gone` error for all requests from `cd.com` except the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

#--redirect  requests to 410 Gone--#
RewriteRule \.*$ - [R=410,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Could you include the cd.com domain in the rule?

Comment: This also redirects `ab.com` .

Comment: Starkeen Yeah, but only URLs from cd.com should be 410-redirected - not ab.com URLs. That's why I would like the domain to be added :-)